# views for home page - django

Tags: django, django-views

I just completed a couple of apps for my django project - The structure of the projects looks as follows:

```
testsite______
              |
              |
           testsite
              |
              |
             news 
              |
              |
            reviews
              |
              |
           templates
              |
              |
           manage.py
```

`news` and `reviews` are 2 apps. Now I want to start work on the home page of the project. The home page would have nothing but 2 hyperlinks right in the middle pointing to each of the apps and some text. Do I write the view for this inside `testsite/testsite`? Or do I create another app to deal with all the home page items?

Comment: Why not just use a ```TemplateView``` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) in your ```urls.py``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new app called `'homepage'` or whatever you want to name it. Take the advantage of `TemplateView`. I am saying to create a new app because this way you would be on a safe side. You might want to add some features on your home page later. So it's always a good idea to follow the real chain.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice here is to create the view inside testsite/testsite as it isn't specific to any one app